# Can ext_pillar be configured depending on pillarenv or saltenv?

Tags: saltstack

I'm looking for a way to select the external pillar depending on saltenv or pillarenv variable.

From saltstack documentation, `ext_pillar` does not support the same syntax as `pillar_roots` (https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/master.html#pillar-roots and https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/master.html#pillar-roots)

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as the [documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/pillar/all/salt.pillar.git_pillar.html) states, use `__env__` keyword. It makes most sense in conjunction with git where branches and tags are representing `pillarenv`s

```
ext_pillar:
  - git:
    - __env__ https://gitserver/git-pillar.git:
      - root: pillar
```